# how can i use a function for different things (don't know how else to word it)

Tags: function, python-3.x

so what I want to do is use a function multiple times like

```
def something():
    x = input('what's your name')
    print('hello', x)
return


something()
something()
something()
```

what I want is those somethings to be given to an individual person.
would I have to do something like this:

```
something.samantha()
something.george()
something.jerald()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to define a *function argument*:

```
def something(x):
    print('hello', x)

something("samantha")
something("george")
something("jerald")
```